# Java Regex Anomaly?

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of address such as the following:

```
Find Dabla Inc at 6889 66th Ave, NY, NY 11884-3773. Call them at (888) 292-1655.
Find Walgreen Drug Stores at 6008 87th Ave, NY, NY 17774-4314. Call them at (888) 999-473
Find Silver Star Restaurant at 6941 99th Ave Ste A, NY, NY 88804-2915. Call them at (888) 851-2799.
```

I am trying to extract the street address, state, city and zip code from this text via Regex.

Currently, I am using the following to match street address:

```
    (?<=at\s)\d{3,5}\s\S*\s\w*.*(?=,)
```

However, I see it inlcudes in match         NY, instead of stopping after the first comma (it only stops after second comma).. Why is it including first comma if I'm using a positive lookahead?

Thannks

Comment: Java.. i thought it was the same for both..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=at\s)\d{3,5}\s\S*\s\w*.*?(?=,)

                            ^^
```

Make your regex `non greedy`.

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/14

Comment: I tried. I got: "Cannot accept an answer in 11 minutes" :) I will wait a little to accept..

Comment: @KimClinton you can also use `(?<=at\s)\d{3,5}\s+[^,]*` a shortened version